# Scraping Javascript in PHP with Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex

I am scraping a site with cURL and returning the output, then putting it through the preg_match() function to retrieve certain things. When I try to scrape the following it       doesn't show anything.

```
preg_match('/var b=new (.*)var p=new /i', $bountyHTML, $ting);
$chou = $ting[1];
echo $chou;
```

The section in $bountyHTML I am trying to scrape from looks like this:

```
<script>
    function fsb(x) {
      var b=new Array(101,55,100,99,52,49,57,50,54,56,51,55,54,49,51,50,101,50,49,50,100,54,49,97,50,53,52,99,100,57,54,53,51,100,49,54,55,38,101,101,49,104,61,101,61,50,50,49,56,99,110,111,78,50,109,114,111,102,38,52,61,100,101,55,105,95,98,116,115,105,51,108,48,116,105,97,104,63,112,104,52,112,97,49,46,121,55,56,52,101,102,54,50,116,110,117,52,111,98,47,101,54,57,52,57,101,53,99,98,102,56,48,98,51);
      var p=new Array(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);       
      var bountyForm = document.getElementById('bountyForm');
      bountyForm.action = c(b,p) + x;
      return true;
    }
  </script>
```

Any ideas why it wouldn't be returning anything? Thanks!

Comment: Add the `s` modifier to match newlines with dots `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/var b=new (.*)var p=new /is', $bountyHTML, $ting);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> s (PCRE_DOTALL) If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s
>   modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting of this modifier.